# What are some good writing tablets for taking notes that are heavy on math/physics?

Tags: note-taking

For the record, I'd like something to replace notebooks. I'm accumulating more and more notebooks, and they're a pain to tug around everywhere. Plus, notebooks are easy to get lost (I've lost notebooks by accidentally leaving them in restrooms), not easily-backup-able, and non-searchable.

So I'd like a tablet that allows me to read PDFs heavy on math/physics, that allows me to easily annotate notes, and that has a thin stylus that allows me to write subscripts and superscripts with ease.

Comment: Maybe this [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37425/best-tablet-computer-for-mathematics-closed) thread adds to the discussion.

Comment: it seems like this (closed) [question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3042/lenovo-thinkpad-tablet-finally-found-the-best-tablet-for-academics) is right on target..

Comment: There are also similar questions, with useful answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193072/tablet-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221991/android-devices-for-reading-textbooks-and-writing-math-by-hand).

Answer (score 6):

I believe the limitation is more on the software that you are using, rather than the tablet itself. So, if you are using an iPad, you can use [UPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/upad/id401643317?mt=8), whereas android tablets users should be looking at something like [Repligo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app) or [ezPdf Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=udk.android.reader).

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the stylus, [this review from MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/156560/2011/05/touchscreen_stylus_roundup.html) strongly recommends the [Wacom Bamboo stylus](http://wacom.com/en/Products/Bamboo/BambooStylus.aspx) for writing notes.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet](http://the-gadgeteer.com/2011/11/16/lenovo-thinkpad-tablet-review/), which designed specifically for stylus use (iPad and the likes are not).

Comment: I got one specifically for the active digitizer - what allows it to use a thin stylus instead of the fat sausage ones - and I love it. The writing is very close to natural - not absolutely perfect, it's still a stylus on a hard surface. At the moment, I think it's the best on the market.

Answer (score 3):

The apps suggested by others for iPad and Android with the necessary stylus-es are not bad. However, if you are looking for something **ONLY** to take notes I would suggest looking at [Boogie Board](http://www.improvelectronics.com/boogie-board-LCD-writing-tablet/boogie-board-rip-LCD-writing-tablet.html). I haven't tried it out myself but I hear its good. Plus, its dirt cheap as compared to tablets. Also, the battery life is insanely high and since it doesn't use a touch interface, you can practically write anything and it will store it as that. There are downsides though, it can't save many PDFs and it can tend to be slow. You might want to check them out.

Answer (score 3):

Try the samsung galaxy note 10.1. With a wacom s pen it seems to be the right choice for people who do write a lot of equations/ want to annotate lecture notes.

Comment: lecturenotes app is particularly useful

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question and my answer: [Device for writing a lecture with a stylus for video lecture recording](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/device-for-writing-a-lecture-with-a-stylus-for-video-lecture-recording/2855#2855)

Short version: any professional tablet pc with an active digitizer (the Wacom ones are the best on market). They cost only a little more than an iPad. IPads are good for goofing off and clicking on your virtual farm but there is an abyss in terms of writing quality.