# Suggested tablets/writing pad for online teaching and giving maths lectures

Tags: mathematics, teaching, online-learning, covid-19

I am a maths masters student, and am looking to buy a tablet/writing pad device. I will primarily be using it for writing when collaborating with a group on a paper, giving lectures/talks, and online tutoring.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions for something suitable (that can be purchased/shipped to the UK), ideally under £50. I would love something that is a decent size (at least 6x8 inch), and which has a screen on which you can see what you are writing.

A [related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/351/what-are-some-good-writing-tablets-for-taking-notes-that-are-heavy-on-math-physi) was closed as being off topic- as a 'shopping question', though I think that it was a perfectly valid. I don't know where else I could ask for advice for this; the students\lecturers that I know have something similar generally have high-end tablets or ipads that are out of my price range, and I am sure many users of this site have good suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, this forum isn't suitable for product recommendations, because they depend on individual preferences and are soon outdated.

Answer (score 0):

XP-Pen is a good off-name cheap brand. However £50 for a device with a 6x8 screen seems unrealistic, especially after the pandemic drove demand up. If budget is your main concern, the first thing I would cut is the screen. Getting used to a tablet without a screen takes some time, a bit like touch-typing, but once you do it it's not that bad and you can get some good deals.